# Labeling image regions

Tags: python, matlab

I have an image containing coloured regions (some of them using the same colour) and I would like that each region have a different colour.

The objective is to colour/label each region using a different colours/labels.

Sample image:

[image]

Comment: Did you look at `bwlabel`? Also do you want a MATLAB or Python solution? There isn't a "one-size-fits-all".

Comment: Yes, the problem is that in my image all regions are connected. bwlabel returns a matrix containing only ones. Actually, I have a segmented image labeled using random values (some of them are repeated) and I would like to label each segment using unique labels. It does not matter a MATLAB, Python or other solution.

Comment: `bwlabel` does **not** return a matrix containing only ones.  It contains an integer matrix from `0` to `N` where `1, 2, ..., N` denotes the membership of a pixel contained within a region.  `0` is the background.  Couldn't you just loop through each unique label and colour the result?  I can provide an answer if you're still unclear.

Comment: That's because `bwlabel` expects a BW (binary) image. If you threshold your image first (and probably invert) you'll get two connected components plus the 0 background..

Comment: Exactly, that is the problem. bwlabel expects a binary image, but I can not create a binary image if there are more than two consecutive regions. I have updated the sample image to better expose the problem. So, I am not sure bwlabel is the solution.

Comment: Please post the image you're using as well as your actual code. If you keep changing the problem, all you'll get is guesswork.

Comment: Sorry. The sample image is the image that I am testing. I do not have any code because I do not have any idea how to solve the problem. I tried the MATLAB funcion bwlabel, but it is not a solution because the image is not a binary image (and I can not convert it because I would lose regions).

Comment: The sample image already is labeled,each with different gray level

Comment: How many labels are you looking for? You have 3 levels of grayscale (plus the background) and you have 8 shapes. What should be the output?

Comment: @rahnema1 I'd assume that two disconnected regions with the same gray level should receive a different label.

Comment: That is exactly what I need, two disconnected regions with the same gray level should receive a different label. The output for the sample image should be an image with 9 different labels. The accepted answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by looping over the unique values in your image, creating a mask of the objects with that value, and performing [`bwlabel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) for each such mask. This will give you unique labels for each connected component in that mask, and you can collect the labels from all the masks by adding the number of labels already found previously:

```
img = imread('i5WLA.png');

index = zeros(size(img));
for iGray = unique(img(:)).'  %'
  mask = (img == iGray);
  L = bwlabel(mask, 4);
  index(mask) = L(mask)+max(index(:));
end

subplot(2,1,1);
imshow(img, []);
title('Original');
subplot(2,1,2);
imshow(index, []);
title('Each region labeled uniquely');
```

And here's the plot this makes:

[image]

You can now see that each connected object has its own unique gray value. You can then create a color image from this new indexed image using either [`ind2rgb`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2rgb.html) or [`label2rgb`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/label2rgb.html) and selecting a colormap to use (here I'm using [`hsv`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2hsv.html)):

```
rgbImage = ind2rgb(index, hsv(max(index(:))));
imshow(rgbImage);
% Or...
rgbImage = label2rgb(index, @hsv);
imshow(rgbImage);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's already a function floating around that does what you want, you can always write it yourself.

If I had to do this, I'd consider something like a union-find algorithm to group all equal-color adjacent/connected pixels into sets, then assign labels to those sets.

A naive (less efficient but doesn't require union-find) implementation using pseudo-code:

```
# assume pixels are stored in numpy array. Use your imagination to adjust as required.
put each pixel into its own set.
for pixel in pixels:
  neighbors = adjacent_same_color_pixels(pixel)
  find the sets that contain pixel, and the sets that contain the neighbors
  join all those sets together, delete the original sets

now there's one set for each connected same-color shape.
assign labels as desired.
```

Comment: MATLAB has several built-in functions for image labeling/connected components/segmentation, so writing your own is probably overkill.

Comment: Yeah I'd  be surprised if it wasn't there already. Just a nice little exercise then.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The accepted answer gets what I need.